# Making an arrow in a pgfplot figure from one point to another?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, arrows

How can I make an arrow from one point in a tikz picture to another point?

In the following example, I would like to draw an arrow from the word data--which is approximately the coordinate (1982, 88)-- and have it point to the coordinate (1985, 82).

```
\documentclass[professionalfont, fleqn]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning}
\graphicspath{{graphics/}}

\begin{document}
\frame
{
\frametitle{Frame Title}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}
       [
         axis x line  = bottom,
         axis y line  = left,
         width        = 1.01\textwidth,
         height       = .63\textwidth,          % Adjusted
         ymax         = 93,
         ymin         = 27,
         ytick        = {30,40,...,90},
         xmax         = 1993,
         xmin         = 1967,
         xtick        = {1970, 1980, ..., 1990},
       ]
       \node[anchor=west] at (axis cs:1968.5,89.5){%
       \textbullet\ Comment here about data
       };
      \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do this using `node`s, such as

```
       \node[anchor=west] (source) at (axis cs:1968.5,89.5){\textbullet\ Comment here about data};
       \node (destination) at (axis cs:1985,82){};
       \draw[->](source)--(destination);
```

which gives

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}
       [
         axis x line  = bottom,
         axis y line  = left,
         width        = 1.01\textwidth,
         height       = .63\textwidth,          % Adjusted
         ymax         = 93,
         ymin         = 27,
         ytick        = {30,40,...,90},
         xmax         = 1993,
         xmin         = 1967,
         xtick        = {1970, 1980, ..., 1990},
       ]
       \node[anchor=west] (source) at (axis cs:1968.5,89.5){\textbullet\ Comment here about data};
       \node (destination) at (axis cs:1985,82){};
       \draw[->](source)--(destination);
      \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

Following the comment, you can connect `node`s using *many* different ways (See Section 3.10 of the `tikz & pgf` manual); you can also customize the arrows (see Section 23 of the manual). For example,

```
\draw[->,>=stealth](source) to [out=90,in=90] (destination);
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help!  That works beautifully.  Is it possible to draw the arrow such that the arrowhead is a little thicker?  Also, is it possible to make the arrow part curvy rather than linear?  That is, say a circle going from 9 o'clock to 6 o'clock (or 9 to 12)?

Comment: @JG You're welcome :) See my edit. Welcome to tex exchange- the best way to say thanks is to upvote answers :) Note that you can upvote more than one answer on every question- it means that folks get 10 points for their time & code

Comment: I tried to upvote.  I have no idea if it worked.  Do you know if it did?

Comment: @JG I can't tell who voted- if the up arrow is coloured brown, then you've done it :)

Comment: The `to` example here requires that `clip=false` be set so that it is visible.

Answer (score 13):

You can directly draw using coordinates:

```
\draw[->] (axis cs:1982, 88) -- (axis cs:1985, 82);
```

within the `axes` environment works. I posted the answer to the same question which has been posted a bit earlier on [LaTeX-Community.org](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=17783).

Much thicker arrow, as requested in the comment:

```
\draw[->,-triangle 60] (axis cs:1982, 88) -- (axis cs:1985, 82);
```

or triangle 45, triangle 90. The `arrows` library offers some. And for a thicker arrow as a whole, add the `thick` or `very thick` option to draw.

And for a curvy arrow you could use the bend option, such as

```
\draw[->,-triangle 60] (axis cs:1982, 88) to[bend right=-60] (axis cs:1985, 82);
```

[image: arrow]

Answer (score 4):

Just to complete the answers on curvy arrows given before:
I found a solution I was being inspired by [this](http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.de/2010/04/bending-arrows-delaying-plot.html) article focusing on gnuplot.

Section 14.10 of the `tikz & pgf` manual provides a similar method by using a parabola to draw a curved arrow between two points. That method gives you some control over how the curve of the arrow should look beyond what can be achieved by the `in` and `out` options of the `to` operation, but easier to use than Bézier curves (section 14.3 of the manual).

You should get a nicely curved arrow by extending your example with the following:

```
\draw[->,>=stealth](source) parabola bend (axis cs:1980,40) (destination);
```

<del>Un</del>fortunately I could<del>n't</del> post a picture of the result since this is my first post *thanks to @diabonas comment*<del>:(</del> :).

[image: Result of the above <code>\draw</code> command]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Comment: Thanks! Your comment made the help of others unnecessary ;).